# "They should be committed"

Tags: verbs

I have come accross a very strange use of the verb "to be committed". It's from the Curious Savage:

DR. EMMETT. How could they possibly have believed you?

MRS. SAVAGE. They should be committed, shouldn't they?

What does the "they should be committed" sentence mean? Does it mean "it's them who should be placed in the "mad house""?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As FumbleFingers has said,

> Yes - it does indeed mean "They're mad, and should be committed (sent, assigned) to a mental institution". Some people today might say it's a bit "non-PC" - along with expressions like "He should be in the looney bin".

Note that ***committed*** in this context has a "domain-specific" legal / medical sense - referred for mental health treatment *against one's will.*